# Inherited resources not indexing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, cancan

I have an activeadmin app, that uses cancan for roles. The admin should be able to see all orders and broker should only see orders that belong to them. Right now broker is working fine, but admin is only seeing orders that belong to that user, instead of all orders in the app.

ability model

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

        return if user.nil? #non logged in user can use this.

        if user.broker?
            can [:index, :create, :read, :update, :new, :edit], [Order, Customer], :admin_user_id => user.id.to_s
            can :read, [OrderCategory, OrderType, OrderStatus, OrderPriority]
            cannot :index, [OrderCategory, OrderType, OrderStatus, OrderPriority]
            cannot :destroy, :all
        end

        if user.art?
            cannot :create, :all
            can :read, :all
            can :update, Order
            cannot :destroy, :all
        end


        if user.shipping?
            can :read, :all
            can :update, Order
            cannot :destroy, :all
        end

        if user.production?
            can [:create, :update], [Order, Customer]
            can :read, :all
        end

        if user.sales?
            can [:create, :read, :update], [Order, Customer]
            cannot :destroy, :all
        end

        if user.admin?
            can :manage, :all
        end
    end
end
```

Order resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order, :sort_order => "end_date_asc" do
    controller.authorize_resource :except => :index

    menu :label => "All Orders", :parent => "Sales", :priority => 2

    filter :name, label: "Order Name"
    filter :admin_user, :collection => proc { AdminUser.all.map{|u| [u.last_name, u.id] } }
    filter :order_category, label: "Category"
    filter :order_type, label: "Type"
    filter :order_status, label: "Status"
    filter :order_priority, label: "Priority"
    filter :customer, label: "Customer"
    filter :start_date, label: "Start Date"
    filter :end_date, label: "Due Date"
    filter :id, label: "Order ID#"

  controller do

     def begin_of_association_chain
      current_user 
    end
    end

    index do 
        selectable_column
        column "ID", :sortable => :id do |order|
            link_to order.id, admin_order_path(order)
        end
        column "Proof" do |order|
            image_tag order.proof_url(:proof).to_s
        end
        column "Name", :sortable => :name do |order|
      link_to order.name, admin_order_path(order)
    end
    column(:customer, :sortable => :customer_id)
    column("Category", :order_category, :sortable => :order_category_id) 
        column("Status", :order_status, :sortable => :order_status_id)
        column("Priority", :order_priority, :sortable => :order_priority_id)
    column("Due Date", :end_date, :sortable => :end_date)
    default_actions
  end


  form :partial => "form"

  show :title => :name do

    panel "Order Details" do
      attributes_table_for resource do
        row :id
        row :admin_user
        row :name
        row :order_category
        row :order_type
        row :order_status
        row :order_priority
        row :start_date
        row :end_date
      end
    end
      resource.line_items.each do |a|
        text_node(render :partial => "admin/line_items/show", :locals => { :line_item => a })
    end
    panel "Art Details" do
        attributes_table_for resource do
            row :print_location
            row :color_front
            row :color_back
            row :color_sleeve
            row(:artwork) do
                image_tag order.artwork_url(:thumb).to_s
            end
            row(:proof) do
                image_tag order.proof_url(:thumb).to_s
            end
          end
      end  
    end
end
```

Comment: I see that you edited the title to indicate `InheritedResource` instead of `CanCan`, but what you are describing is not an error. As I showed in my answer, you are explicitly telling your code to behave in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `CanCan` has anything to do with your current problem. This code:

```
def begin_of_association_chain
  current_user 
end
```

modifies the `InheritedResource` scope that is used to fetch the list of model objects. You're telling your controller that you always want `current_user` to be the first scope applied to your queries.